# What is the best way to run separate thread in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I have a react application, and I need a thread/process outside of the main thread to run some functions every hour, or even every day.

I don't know how to implement this, whether create a new API using Java or other app, or use js' setInterval() technique. I found nodejs Worker Threads too. But I don't know what is the best way to implement it.

The process itself is getting a data (an array) from public API, and process the data periodically, it will be a 'stay online' process since I want to run this in a cloud and stay online for a long time.

So, can I have any suggestion of how to implement this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if your server supports cron and crontab, adding your script there (`node /path/to/script.js`) would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lib [Node Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

or you can use node.js built in lib **child_process**

[spawn(), exec(), execFile(), and fork()](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/)

Comment: Regarding node schedule I can say that we use it in production and it is really reliable (hasn't failed us yet) and offers various timing options so that you should be able to implement most variations you might need.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use thread then latest version of node.js has support for [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads). If you want to use a separate process then [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is what you are looking for.

Here is an article about how to [parse json using worker_thread](https://anotherdev.xyz/nodejs-worker-thread-json-parse/). Using same method you can do any CPU intensive task in a separate thread without blocking the main thread.